# Inconsitent TypeScript behavior with union and object type

Tags: typescript

Let's have a following snippet:

```
interface A {
  isEmpty(x: any[] | string | object): boolean;
  isEmptyObject(x: object): boolean;
}

const a: A = <A>{};

a.isEmptyObject({});
a.isEmptyObject({a: 1});

a.isEmpty([]);
a.isEmpty('');
a.isEmpty({});
a.isEmpty({a: 1});
```

When I try to compile it, it crashes with this:

```
a.ts(14,12): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ a: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | object | any[]'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'a' does not exist in type 'string | object | any[]'.
```

How is this possible, when the union type (`string | object | any[]`) contains type `object` for which it works (the `isEmptyObject` call with `{a: 1}` is fine)?

Main question: Is this a TypeScript bug, or how one should write that input may be an array of any value or string or object (but not any primitive, I don't want `any` or `Object`)?

Tested with TypeScript 2.3.4.

Comment: @adiga I don't see how this is relevant. I am nowhere accessing any fields from the `x` argument which is of the union type.

Comment: Does rearranging the union type change anything? No idea why this happens, but I'm curious now.

Comment: @monnef sorry. I realized that and deleted it

Comment: @Carcigenicate I tried it in playground and the order doesn't seem to have any effect :-/.

Comment: @monnef Damn. I only used TS for like a month, so I'm just shooting in the dark. Looks like a bug, but this wouldn't be the first thing that appeared to be a bug, but was actually some fringe case for TS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug but a feature to support API-s which utilizes argument objects. Take for example jQuery-s ajax function. It takes an object as an argument.

```
interface JQueryAjaxParam {
    url: string;
    data?: any;
}

...

$.ajax({
    url: "",
    datta: "" // notice the typo here
});
```

**You do want a compilation error in this case**, even though `{url:"",datta:""}` implements the param interface. To overcome this they added [excess property checks for *object literals as direct parameters*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks). **This is a good thing**, provides more confidence in the typechecker, and only causes false errors when people try to conduct quick tests like yours. You have to keep this rule in mind, this is the cost of additional safety.

**UPDATE:** TypeScript 2.4 additionally introduces [Weak types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/06/12/announcing-typescript-2-4-rc/#user-content-weak-types)

So then there are functions with this signature:

```
function isEmptyObject(x : object) : void;
```

Here, the intention is clear, this function aims to accept any object with any keys. A function accepting only empty object has little use. So they added an exception: when the parameter is of the type `object` exactly, then the previous check is omitted.

So what to do? Nothing. In real uses your function will typecheck just fine. You can try it:

```
interface A {
  isEmpty(x: any[] | string | object): boolean;
  isEmptyObject(x: object): boolean;
}

const a: A = <A>{};
const param = {a: 1};

a.isEmptyObject({});
a.isEmptyObject(param);

a.isEmpty([]);
a.isEmpty('');
a.isEmpty({});
a.isEmpty(param);
```

**UPDATE**

Your example is an actual usecase, you want it to work even with literals. After Nitzan, I too suggest to use *function overloading* for this.

```
interface A {
    isEmpty(x: any[]): boolean;
    isEmpty(x: string): boolean;
    isEmpty(x: object): boolean;
    isEmptyObject(x: object): boolean;
}

const a: A = <A>{};
a.isEmptyObject({b: 6});
a.isEmptyObject({a: 1});

a.isEmpty([]);
a.isEmpty('');
a.isEmpty({});
a.isEmpty({a: 1});
```

Comment: This is a real use - I am wrapping an existing function from library to fix typings. I *need* array of any type or string or non-primitive (= `object`). I don't see a reason why would I ever wanted `object` to mean "only empty object" when it is defined as a non-primitive. It doesn't really seem like a good thing to me, when type checking is non transitive ._.

Comment: So this is related to the `suppressExcessPropertyErrors` compiler option?

Comment: @monnef I see your point. Let me experiment a bit and update my answer

Comment: @cartant maybe, I did not know about that compiler option. Sounds like it is.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I am not very happy with the way TS solves the issue (I would prefer `object` always meaning non-primitive and only via some explicit keyword or symbol to enable that "excess property errors").

Comment: @monnef Yep. I guess we just witnessed some implementation detail leaking into the usage. Maybe it's worth opening a discussion thread on github.

Comment: It seems that it is actually a bug in TypeScript compiler - https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/17007. I am relieved, because it was really weird behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is failing the compilation on the following condition:

`Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'a' does not exist in type 'string | object | any[]'.`

Basically `{ a: 1 }` is not convertible to type `object`.

You could do it this way:

```
interface A {
    isEmpty(x: any[] | string | { [index: string]: any }): boolean;
    isEmptyObject(x: { [index: string]: any }): boolean;
}
```

EDIT: after another look at the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) it is possibly explained by:

> Union types can be a bit tricky here, but it just takes a bit of intuition to get used to. If a value has the type A | B, we only know for certain that it has members that both A and B have. In this example, Bird has a member named fly. We can’t be sure whether a variable typed as Bird | Fish has a fly method. If the variable is really a Fish at runtime, then calling pet.fly() will fail.

Comment: This can't be true - `{a: 1}` clearly is convertible to `object`, because `a.isEmptyObject({a: 1});` works without any warning or error.

Comment: Please format code using indentation instead of backticks for larger chunks. Backticks render any larger chunks fairly unreadable.

Comment: Hmm after another look at the docs I think it is due to the way union types are combining 'any[] and object'. See my edit

Comment: @SeanSobey It seems the quote from docs relates to usage of a variable/parameter of union type - I am not using anywhere the `x`, it's only interface (to show how it is not passing typecheck).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily go around this problem by adding another signature:

```
interface A {
    isEmpty(x: any[]): boolean;
    isEmpty(x: string | object): boolean;
    isEmptyObject(x: object): boolean;
}

a.isEmpty({ a: 1 }); // fine now
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isEmpty(x%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isEmpty(x%3A%20string%20%7C%20object)%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isEmptyObject(x%3A%20object)%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%3A%20A%20%3D%20%3CA%3E%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aa.isEmptyObject(%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0Aa.isEmptyObject(%7Ba%3A%201%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aa.isEmpty(%5B%5D)%3B%0D%0Aa.isEmpty('')%3B%0D%0Aa.isEmpty(%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0Aa.isEmpty(%7Ba%3A%201%7D)%3B))

---

#### Edit

I don't think that it's a bug, if anything is a bug it's the error message which isn't very helpful.

What I think that happens is that you can use `object` in a union with any primitive types without a problem (in your case), but once you introduce a non-primitive type then you'll get the error, for example:

```
isEmpty(x: string | object | Map<string, string>): boolean;
```

Will result in the same error.
The union of `object` (which is anything that isn't primitive) and another non-primitive type probably results in a type that cannot be matched and the compiler gets confused.

You are welcome to open a new issue on this case, if you do please share the link here, I'd like to see what they say.

Comment: But why is that necessary?

Comment: So it is a TypeScript bug? Or why do I have to jump through these hoops?

Comment: @Carcigenicate & OP check my revised answer